# Macro Not Pasting on Cell A10

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub fadfadsf()
'Declare variables
    Dim DataRg As Range
    Dim DataCell As Range
    Dim P As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim I As Long
'Set variables
    P = Worksheets("EquipOtherPortfolio").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Q = Worksheets("Modifiedby RDS_EquipmentOther").UsedRange.Rows.Count
''Type If condition to relate the variables I and Q
    If I = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Modifiedby RDS_EquipmentOther").UsedRange) = 0 Then Q = 0
    End If
'Set range for Dataset1
    Set DataRg = Worksheets("EquipOtherPortfolio").Range("J2:J2" & P)

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Apply the For loop
    For I = 1 To DataRg.Count
'Set Condition for "" value
        If CStr(DataRg(I).Value) = "Files" Then
- - '**Apply command to copy cells ' When I change **"A" to "A10"** it will not show any resluts not sure where is the disconnect.**
            DataRg(I).EntireRow.Range("I1:N1").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Modifiedby RDS_EquipmentOther").Range("A" & Q + 1)
           Q = Q + 1
           
           
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

In apply command to copy cell section I tried changing "A" to "A10" but is not showing me results and could not figured out how to change variables.

Comment: Please remove the `on Error Resume Next`, and report back if any line throws an error, and the error message if so.

Comment: `Set DataRg = Worksheets("EquipOtherPortfolio").Range("J2:J2" & P)` - likely that should be `...Range("J2:J" & P)`.

Comment: Did the changes and error out when I remove the on Error Resume Next. Seems like it did not recognized Cell A10 as the range.

Comment: And what error did it give you on which line?

Comment: This line I change A to A10 -"DataRg(I).EntireRow.Range("I1:N1").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Modifiedby RDS_EquipmentOther").Range("A10" & Q + 1)". error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: You definitely don't want `A10`, just `A`.

Comment: @BigBen, I think it worked but then every time I run the macro it will will paste  to the last info(cell) even if I deleted the data. I guess I will just need to actually delete the rows so it will pasted in A10, just for testing purposes. This is resolve thanks again everyone!

Comment: @BigBen, How do I put more than one value in the condition? This Line If CStr(DataRg(I).Value) <> "Files" then.... I want to add more value like Contract and Company.

Comment: `If CStr(DataRg(I).Value) <> "Files" And CStr(DataRg(I).Value) <> "Contract" And CStr(DataRg(I).Value) <> "Company" Then`

Comment: I have this field "Financials - S/T PPD Rent - Financing - 01/01/2030 -  - 623.91 - Inactive" How do you code if you want to exclude this based on the word "Financial"? I have this code "If CStr(DataRg(I).Value) <> "$Financials$" Then". Thanks